# joystick control/navigation using python in ros

Tags: ros, python, joy-node, joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Hackers,

I'm a beginner in ros. I want to get some data from joystick. I'm a python fan - don't much know the cpp.

I would like to connect my joystick in a usb port, and want to create a node(/package) that gives the datas from joystick ,so that I can directly use it to control my robot.

My Doubts

1. How I can link the joystick motion control into my robot?
2. Is it any additional drivers/installation needed to sopport my joystick?
3. Is it I can able to imperilment it using python?
4. Is it any additional requirements/specifications needed for the joystick?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57064/joystick-control/navigation-using-python-in-ros/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's actually a good demonstration of the advantages of ROS supporting multiple languages. There is a C++ joystick node ready to use that should work with nearly all joysticks/gamepads out of the box: [joy](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joy).

Provided you have a roscore running, it's very likely that starting

```
rosrun joy joy_node
```

in one terminal and running

```
rostopic echo joy
```

in another will print out the joystick state. If that's not the case look at the [Configuring and Using a Linux-Supported Joystick with ROS](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joy/Tutorials/ConfiguringALinuxJoystick) tutorial.

Using the joystick data in your python node is just a matter of subscribing to it and performing some processing based on it. A example of doing that is this [joy_teleop.py](http://utexas-art-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stacks/art_vehicle/art_teleop/scripts/joy_teleop.py) node.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-03-04**:
Is that really working in groovy? "rosdep install joy" does not install anything for me.  Otherwise pygame supports juystick and it is easy to write a Python node that uses that.

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-03-04**:
Hi TommyP,  How can you write it using pygame library - Is it there any tutorial available for this

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-05**:
Install the driver with `sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-joystick-drivers`.